# Using cx_Oracle converting query output to dictonary object

Tags: python, cx-oracle

When using the cx_oracle module in python , when i run a query and print the output, it gives it as a tuple object. However I want to have the output as a dictionary object having it neatly : 
{,'' , ,'' , ,'' , }

is there a quick thing I can do for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a method to do this. Below is the relevant code snippet:

```
column_name = [column1,column2,column3]
 for row in cur:
        list_row = list(row) # convert the tuple row to a list type. 
        final = zip(column_names,list_row) # zip the two lists.  
        dict_final = dict(final) # Convert the resulting final list to a dictionary.
```

I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but this is what I came up with.